# AngularJS: Set private service variable in callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do this:

```
app.service('productsService', ['$http', productsService]);

function productsService($http){

    return {
        getProducts: getProducts
    }

    var _products = [];

    function getProducts(){

        $http.get('http://localhost:4000')
            .then(function(data){
                _products = data;
            });
        }
}
```

But at the **then** callback **_products** is an undefined variable.

What is the correct way to set _products value from the then callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the variable before the return statement.

```
app.service('productsService', ['$http', productsService]);

function productsService($http){
    var _products = [];

    return {
        getProducts: getProducts
    }

    //var _products = []; this will never run

    function getProducts(){

        $http.get('http://localhost:4000')
            .then(function(data){
                _products = data;
            });
        }
}
```